# sendgrid - set contact id while Add or Update

Tags: python, sendgrid

I'm trying to use Add or Update a contact endpoint (https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact) and I can see `list_ids` that can be used to set IDs for the contact, but I can't uses it and I don't see it in curl, when I added it to the request I got error 400 bad request, any idea about how to use it ?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how you are calling the endpoint? what's the header and payload etc?
400 error code usually indicates you are sending a request in malformed syntax or an invalid request that the server cannot process.

Comment: I'm using the same snippiest in the link I sent but I added this to the data to be :
data = {
    "list_ids": ["1"],
    "contacts": [
        {
            "email": "ryan39@lee-young.com"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full code you are using to call the API?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the docs that you share, **the user ID of the SendGrid Marketing Contacts is the user email**.

> If the contact already exists in the system, any entries submitted via
> this endpoint will update the existing contact. The contact to update
> will be determined only by the email field and any fields omitted from
> the request will remain as they were. A contact's ID cannot be used to
> update the contact.

In this manner, you can add or update contacts using a payload like that:

```py
payload = {
    "contacts": [
        {
            "email": "name@email.xyz",
            "first_name": "My name",
            "last_name": "My family name",
        }
    ]
}
```